# How to remove the comma of ArrayList element

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I have an Arraylist with Integers for example: "1,600" 
I want to remove the commas from every element. I just saw some ways to remove a entire element of an ArrayList so that´s what I've tried:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1,600");
    list.add("2");
    list.add("3");
    list.add("4");
    list.add("5");
    list.remove((","));

    ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size());

    for (String myInt : list) {

        l.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt));


    }

    int x = l.get(0);
    int y = l.get(1);
    System.out.println(x+y);

}
```

But that just removes if there´s an element with the value comma.
How can I remove the commas of the Integers to get: "1600"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this in your `for-loop` before parsing the String and adding to your list.

```
myInt = myInt.replaceAll(",", "");
```

Thereby, you replace all occurences of `,` with empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for you. Just added a replace in your for-loop to get rid of the commas.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("1,600");
list.add("2");
list.add("3");
list.add("4");
list.add("5");
list.remove((","));

ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>(list.size());

for (String myInt : list) {
    l.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt.replaceAll(",", "")));
}

int x = l.get(0);
int y = l.get(1);
System.out.println(x + y);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (String myInt : list) {

        l.add(Integer.valueOf(myInt.replaceAll(",", "")));

    }
```